# Aligning a submenu

Tags: html, css, submenu

I'm trying to align the submenu in the image but even I have found the code in the template I'm still stuck with it.

[image link](http://bit.ly/IfGKtP)

```
/* sub sub menu*/
.sf-menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: -999em;
    padding: 32px 0 21px;
    background: #c7c7c7 url('../images/bg_sub2.jpg') 0 0 repeat-x;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific and tell what you want to achieve

Comment: the arrow of second sub menu (drum, bass, guitar, ...) must be aligned to "TRACKING". Please, see the image. Thanks.

Comment: is the image of the popup sub menu thing just a box or a box and the arrow? If you have the background image "bg_sub2" to be the entire box and arrow you either have to push the whole entire box down for the arrow to line up. Or you can create a absolute positioned element taht is just the little arrow and move that around based on what menu you've chosen. Option one is easier but may not look as nice

Comment: you need to provide a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Kierchon you gave me the right idea, I've just moved he arrow to match  the "TRACKING" voice-menu. It is not anymore necessary to move all the sub-sub menu but I'd to know why I moved the arrow using position:relative; top:value; and not the whole box.
Since it is the first time i ask here for help, how can I add point to you? 
Thanks

Comment: @Neuran I posted an answer you can check that as you answer by clicking the check mark on the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move just the arrow image with margin or top value based on what is selected.